# Substitute Html.app in update version of MVCTodo

Tags: elm

I want to update the Elm [MVC Todo](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/elm) replacing [old version](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/elm/elm-package.json) in `elm-package.json` for new ones. My new `elm-package.json` is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "summary": "TodoMVC created with Elm and elm-html",
    "repository": "https://github.com/somenxavier/minuscule.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [
        "."
    ],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
        "elm-lang/dom": "1.1.1 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "elm-lang/virtual-dom": "2.0.4 <= v < 2.1.0",
        "elm-lang/navigation": "2.1.0 <= v < 2.2.0",
        "elm-community/string-extra": "1.4.0 <= v < 1.5.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}
```

but `elm-reactor` complains me

```
I cannot find module 'Html.App'. Module 'Todo' is trying to import it.
```

I know `html.app` is [obsolete](https://github.com/evancz/start-app), but how to replace its references in code? Specifically, how to replace this

```
Html.App.map (\msg -> UpdateTask ( id, msg )) taskView
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [upgrade documentation for Elm 0.18](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md). Specifically:

> `elm-lang/html` collapsed `Html.App` into `Html`. So you need to remove any import `Html.App` imports and refer to `Html.program` instead.

`Html.App.map` is now [`Html.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#map).